# Why does "ip -4 route add 31.1.1.1/32 dev wg0" break EC2 networking with WireGuard

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, routing, wireguard

***Edit: Whilst explaining, I finally figured out the error in my logic. The test ip I was using to route to, is the same IP I was connecting with. Thus messing up my connection the moment I changed routing.***

This might be simple, or really complex. I have two EC2 nodes. Both are under my complete control.

I need to route all traffic to a specific IP, lets say 31.1.1.1 from one node via the other. Basically a typical VPN setup where all trafic to 31.1.1.1 is routed via the VPN instead of the regular gateway. Like so.

```
Client Node --> Server Node --> 31.1.1.1
Client Node --> Default GW --> www.google.com
```

I want to use and have setup WireGuard for this;

The Server

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = -------------------
ListenPort = 51820
Address = 10.20.40.1/24
PostUp   = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = -------------------
AllowedIPs = 10.20.40.0/24
```

The Client

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = -------------------
ListenPort = 51820
Address = 10.20.40.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = -------------------
Endpoint = x.x.x.x:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.20.40.0/24
```

I start up Wireguard `wg-quick up wg0` on both machines, and they can ping each other perfectly. All seems to work.
I bring down Wireguard on the client machine and edit the allowed IP's bit; `AllowedIPs = 10.20.40.0/24, 31.1.1.1/32`, I then start Wireguard again. That results in immediately breaking all network connections on the client machine. I can't SSH to it, I can't use RDP or any other network connection. It takes hard rebooting via the EC2 console to reach that machine again.

The offending command is, I think `ip -4 route add 31.1.1.1/32 dev wg0` since when I issue that on either client or server machine, I reproduce the netwerk outage.

Is this an issue with AWS EC2? Can I even change the routing on those systems?
Or is the command as it stands simply wrong?

**Edit:
Routing tables and other information, as requested**

Before

```
Server
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ip-172-31-16-1. 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens5
172.31.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 ens5
ip-172-31-16-1. 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens5


Client
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens5
172.31.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 ens5
172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens5
```

After

```
Server
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens5
10.20.40.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
172.31.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 ens5
172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens5

Client
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens5
10.20.40.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
172.31.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 ens5
172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens5
```

I've only masked the real server ip, if that is bothersome, let me know. The other hidden items are just the keys.
Doing route `ip route add 31.1.1.1/32 via 10.20.40.1` doesn't result in network issue, but some routing does, these don't break it

```
ip route add 31.1.1.1/32 via 10.20.40.1
ip route add 8.8.8.8/32 via 10.20.40.1
```

These do break it

```
ip route add 31.21.203.46/32 via 10.20.40.1
ip route add 31.21.203.0/24 via 10.20.40.1
```

Comment: I don't know much about wireguard unfortunately. What if you do `ip route add 31.1.1.1/32 dev lo`? Or route a different IP to `wg0`? Also as you say you can ping each other - how about routing it as `ip route add 31.1.1.1/32 via 10.20.40.1`? (or whatever the remote ip is)

Comment: Your obfuscating of addresses here makes this difficult to help. You also should consider giving us the full route tables on the both sides of the VPN, without Wireguard running, and with Wireguard running.  You probably have a route wrong, but we simply don't have enough information to tell you which one.